# Are re.search() and re.findall() different in finding regex patterns (Python)?

Tags: python, regex

the demonstration of my question is given below:

My code :

```
p = "goalgoalgoalgoalllllgoaloaloal'

print(re.search('g(oal){3}',p).group())

re.findall('g(oal){3}',p)
```

Output:

```
goaloaloal
['oal']
```

With the same regex pattern, re.search() finds the match to be 'goaloaloal' as I expected. However, `re.findall()` finds the match to be 'oal', which really surprises me. Could anyone please help to explain the cause of the difference? Thank you in advance:-)

Explanation: Sorry for the seemingly duplicate. My original purpose of this question is to find the exact difference between re.research() and re.findall() methods while dealing with the parenthesis in regex pattern. I even didn't know the term "capture" before. More specifically, I wanted to know how to extract exactly the 'goaloaloal' pattern using re.findall() method. Thanks @blhsing for the helpful answer!

Comment: Could you please provide the code as text instead of a screenshot. It will help others to reproduce the issue.

Comment: [You should not post code as an image because:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Comment: Sure! I will avoid posting a picture in the future. Sorry, I am new here.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `re.findall()` returns only the substring in the capture group when there is one, while `re.search()` returns a `Match` object, and when you call the `group()` method of the `Match` object, it returns the substring that matches the entire regex regardless of capture groups.

If you want `re.findall()` to return the entire matching substring, you should use non-capturing groups instead:

```
re.findall('g(?:oal){3}', p) # returns ['goaloaloal']
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of grouping. re.findall returns list of all matched groups except zero group I think. Groups are denoted by round brackets so in your code you have one group `(oal)`. If you denote group which contains all the expression, you'll get the result:

```
import re

p = 'goalgoalgoalgoalllllgoaloaloal'

m = re.search('(g(oal){3})', p)
print(m.group())  # goaloaloal

m = re.findall('(g(oal){3})', p)
print(m)  # [('goaloaloal', 'oal')]
```